# Outlook converts HTML code with MsoNormal and changes size of image

Tags: html, css, outlook

We've got an application which opens a new E-Mail with Outlook 2013 based on custom code. The code is

```
<img width="298px" height="28px" src="https://www.ahd.de/sites/default/files/logo_0.gif"/>
```

but Outlook opens the E-Mail with the following:

```
<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;
mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";color:#6E6E6E;mso-no-proof:yes'><img
width=1024 height=768 id="_x0000_i1025"
src="https://www.ahd.de/sites/default/files/logo_0.gif"
alt="ahd your business. (Logo)"></span><span style='font-size:10.0pt;
font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
color:#6E6E6E'>
```

Is there any way around this? The image ist hugely out off proportion in the mail.

Note: The funny bit is, that when I close the Outlook window  and reopen it through our application, the code is still changed, but with the correct width and height!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: use it something like this: `<img alt="your alt text" border="0" height="28" src="https://www.ahd.de/sites/default/files/logo_0.gif" style="width: 298px; height:28px;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;margin: 0px;border: 0;" width="298" />`

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Thanks, that seems to have worked! Would you spare the time to explain why?

Also, can I mark your commant as an eligible answer to my question?

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime when we are writing codes for *Email Templates* we should follow *inline CSS* always and if we want to use *images* then we must follow in this particular manner as(viz the OP case):

```
<img alt="your alt text" border="0" height="28" src="https://www.ahd.de/sites/default/files/logo_0.gif" style="width: 298px; height:28px;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;margin: 0px;border: 0;" width="298" />
```

The main reasons behind this are:

- Always provide `alt` text of your image tag
- Always set `border` to zero to avoid unnecessary border that most of the mailer clients put around your image
- And most important of them all, always **fix `height` and `width` of your image in both manners, i.e. using *inline CSS* as well as using image tag `attributes` to restrict the area of your image covers to its actual dimensions in all platforms.

Hope this will make things clear for you.